# Modifying Registry Using VBScript

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to write a vbscript utility that will add or remove several related registry keys. However, I cannot seem to find a code that will work.

What is the code for removing a registry key? What is the code for restoring a key (with values)? Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My google-fu got me this:

Some library-ish code:
http://www.naterice.com/articles/35

Some example scripts:
http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/registry/